# can I use dataSource as variable name in a gsp view?

Tags: grails

Is it possible to declare a dataSource variable in a view and cause the destruction of grails?

In this part of the application the requirement is to add dataSources for an ingestion process run by a quartz job. The dataSources track the parameters of the quartz job and the execution for the job. It is a crud interface for the dataSources.

I used a variable in a grails view called dataSource and a list called dataSources for the model returned by the controller. Everything works fine but I have been told it is confusing despite the fact that this part of the app is used to edit dataSources for the app.

Is it appropriate to use a variable called dataSource in a gsp? Does this cause confusion with the grails dataSource?

Comment: Its not good idea to access dataSource from gsp, you would almost never need to do that. What are you trying to achieve actually? What's the requirement. If you explain what you are trying to implement, people will have better suggestions for you

Comment: @sudhir I agree which is why I do not think using dataSource as a name is a bad thing. I'm basically being told this is like using a keyword for a variable name and I disagree.